# Extend User Model from Django?

Tags: python, django

How I create new Users:

```
from twittexApp.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from twittexApp.models import RegUser, User

class RegisterView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'register.html'
    model = RegUser
    success_url = '/login/'
    form_class = UserCreationForm
```

My extended User Model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    class RegUser(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User)
        description = models.CharField(max_length = 140, default="foo")
```

My question is how do I get the attribute "description" from an user?

I already know that I can get the "standard" user model via

```
<h1>My Profile</h1>
<ul>
    <div>{{ request.user.username }}</div>
</ul>
```

But getting the description doesnt work. I tried 2 different versions but it doesnt show "foo".

```
<h1>My Profile</h1>
<ul>
    <div>{{ request.user.desciption }}</div>
    <div>{{ request.user.reguser.desciption }}</div>
</ul>
```

Comment: desciption != description

Answer (score 2):

Maybe is a fool answer but you have a miss spell.

Change:

{{ request.user.desciption }}

For this:

{{ request.user.description }}

Answer (score 1):

```
{{ request.user.reguser.description }}
```

You can access "reverse" side of the relation. In this case `user.reguser`. Also check, if `user` has related `RegUser` instance.